# Оптимизация работы с памятью в С++

Tags: c++, память

решил написать свой .obj парсер, и столкнулся с небольшой проблемой...

```
...

std::vector<Math::Vector4<float>> vertices;

std::string line;
std::ifstream inputStream(objFileName);
while (std::getline(inputStream, line))
{
    if (line.substr(0, 2) == "v ")
    {
        std::istringstream stream(line.substr(2));
        float x, y, z;
        stream >> x;
        stream >> y;
        stream >> z;
        vertices.push_back({ x, y, z, 1.0f });
    }

    ... // Texture coordinate, normals e.t.c.
}
```

Вопрос заключается в следующем, можно ли как-то оптимизировать в данном случае работу с памятью, но так сказать не во вред удобности? При substr постоянно же будет аллоцироваться новая строка, да и при создании стрима. Хотелось бы как-то ограничиться парой выделений памяти и все на этом, а не фрагментировать кучу такими маленькими выделениями(вектор в дальнейшем будет заменен, так как тоже очень затратно будет происходить реаллоцирование памяти, пока просто хотел бы разобраться со строками)...

Comment: может вам просто делать `scanf("v %f %f %f")`?

Comment: конечно выделите простую строку  char[] и делайте sscanf, scanf не очень хорошая функция, если ей входной формат не нравится, то она будет делать ungetc

Comment: Можно упомянуть, что std::string имеет Small String Optimization и при маленьких строчках (<=15 символов) не происходит аллокации памяти

Comment: @Beaver Feller: Не "std::string имеет", а "некоторые реализации std::string имеют". И решение это весьма неоднозначное в смысле своей полезности.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В современном С++ всю работу с константными/немодифиуируемыми [под]строками имеет смысл переводить на использование `std::string_view`. То есть везде, где в вашей программе явно или концептуально выступает `const std::string &` он должен быть заменен на `const std::string_view &`. Это относится и к вашему применению `substr`. Нет никаких причин формировать целый новый `std::string` объект только ради выделения немодифицируемой подстроки.

По уму и `std::string::substr` должен был бы возвращать `std::string_view`, а не `std::string`, но так исторически сложилось и сейчас уже не переделать.

В данном случае можно предложить заменить все

```
line.substr(i, j)
```

на

```
std::string_view(line).substr(i, j)
```

Это избавит вас от ненужных промежуточных `std::string` объектов и сопутствующего выделения памяти.

Или уже с самого начала вы могли после получения `line` сразу сформировать

```
std::string_view line_view = line;
```

и дальше работать исключительно с `line_view`.

Это, однако, не избавит вас от выделения памяти при инициализации `std::istringstream` и внутри `std::istringstream`. Здесь бы бы полезен парсер для `std::string_view`, но готового в стандартной библиотеке нет (кроме `sscanf`). Сама стандартная библиотека еще толком не перешла на использование `std::string_view`.

---

Ваше

```
vertices.push_back({ x, y, z, 1.0f });
```

это тоже потенциально - ненужное копирование. Возможно, что лучше

```
vertices.emplace_back(x, y, z, 1.0);
```

но это уже зависит от свойств `Math::Vector4<float>`.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, а в чем отличие push_back и emplace_back?
Плохо понимаю этот момент...